# Can you add the option "Open with X" to the right-click menu of a folder?

Tags: 20.04

If I want to open a folder with Microsoft Visual Studio Code, I have to right-click -> Open With Other Application -> select Visual Studio Code -> click "Select".

Is it possible to add the option "Open with MVSC" directly to the right-click menu?

Comment: In Nautilus/Files, if you right-click a file with the extension of the files you want to open with Visual Studio Code, then choose Properties and the Open With tab, you may be able to add it and/or make it the default?

Comment: @linux4me Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I want to open *folders* with VSC, and folders do not have "open with" in properties. And even if they did, I would not want the default application that opens folders to be VSC haha.